# How to diff two files in NAnt

Tags: nant

How can I diff 2 text files using NAnt to produce a file containing the differences?

Comment: I don't think NAnt has a built in tool.  I suggest using a command line diff tool and call it via <exec>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `<exec>` task and call cmd with `fc` command that compares files. It will look something like that

```
<exec program="cmd.exe" commandline="/C fc file1 file2" />
```

You can see `fc` manpage [here](http://ss64.com/nt/fc.html)